# Questions about where to find resources on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Is this question on topic?

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/where-can-i-download-midi-files-of-videogame-music

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see any reason that would be on topic, no. However, it seems to be asked with the intent of remixing, which is related to audio and video production at least a little.

Probably OK to leave it for now, as it has a good answer.

If there are a proliferation of "where do I download X" questions that would be bad, but one example with a remix slant is not necessarily an issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with an answer to this, but I tend towards **yes**. On the one hand, looking for resources for remixing or composing has traditionally [been](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/where-to-find-music-beats) [on-topic](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/where-can-i-find-animal-sounds). But on the other, the question seems to be just one step away from, say "where can I download mp3s?" which would clearly be off-topic here.

The problem I've had is that I can't find a clear distinction. Where is that line exactly? I don't want to start telling people what they can and can't post if I can't even figure it out for myself.

For this question, I decided that editing it so it was more clearly aimed at remixing was the best idea. This is a legitimate question that I've heard several times in recording/remixing contexts so answering it has clearly has value to someone. But whether it's appropriate *here* is something I'd still like to hear the community's opinion on.